# Retrieve records from DB whose relations all have condition active=1 in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm a little stuck on an Eloquent query. I have 2 objects, Recipes and Ingredients. Recipes can hold many ingredients. Ingredients can be set to active or not.
What I'm trying to achieve is to run a query that returns only recipes with active ingredients. So if one or more of a recipe's ingredients is set to not active, I do not want the Recipe in the result at all.

What I've got so far is

```
$recipes = Recipe::with(['ingredients' => function($query){
    $query->where('active', 1);
}, 'image', 'user',  'ingredients.unit', 'comments.user'])->where('share', 1)->get();
```

But this just leaves out not active ingredients.

Hoping that someone can point in me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you are filtering your ingredients instead of that you should use whereDoesntHave method. Change your code like this.

```
Recipe::where('share', 1)->whereDoesntHave('ingredients' , function($query) 
{
    $query->where('active', '=', 0);
})->with(['image', 'user',  'ingredients.unit', 'comments.user'])->get();
```

Try it out. [Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)